# How bulk update with Model to Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How bulk update with Model to Laravel 5.4?

Model Brand

```
class Brand extends Model
{
   use BulkInsertOrUpdate;

   ...
}
```

[My trait](https://gist.github.com/plehanov/de850560d15d7cedac57497491ca8533#file-bulkinsertorupdate-php) for this operation

Sample using -

`Brand::bulkInsertOrUpdate($array, 'title');`
or
`Brand::bulkInsertOrUpdate($array, ['title', 'slug']);`

Is there an easier way to have a bulk upload? How much I understood standard method updateOrCreate works only with one tuple

Comment: Do you want to upload bulk video files or image files?

Comment: Items in database

Comment: Ok you want multiple image upload in database?

Comment: No, simple records

Comment: ok. then you first create migration , then controller and then model file

Comment: I was wondering if there are any simple ways to bulk update or write data through models instead of using my trait file. Your questions are off topic @HaninderSingh

Comment: @HaninderSingh Yes, I created it all, and I use trait for mass recording in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get all images in Array once you get it just use for or foreach loop for insert/update Array Images.

Comment: Hi, the comments under the answer indicate that the original question was meant to for plain database records, not images. The reason people often want bulk insert/update operations is speed related, especially when using an ORM